# Group items from database by event

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in my database: *reservations*, *events* and *users*. I want to display all the users that subscribed to a certain event. The tables are linked via the following method:

```
SELECT users.u_name, events.e_id, events.e_title
FROM users
INNER JOIN reservations
ON reservations.r_s_id = users.u_id
INNER JOIN events
ON reservations.r_event_id = events.e_id
```

I need to join the reservation table because the field *reservations.r_s_id* correlates with the unique id of the user (*users.u_id*) and then the field *reservations.r_event_id* correlates with the unique id of the events (*events.e_id*). This was the only method i could come up with to approach all the necessary values.

It is my goal to get an output like below but have no clue how to achieve this

```
Event 1
 - user 1
 - user 3
 - user 9
Event 2
 - User 2
 - User 5
 - User 12
```

I tried using `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY` on *events.e_title* but that did not resulted the way i want it to

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select from reservations, order the result set by `events.e_id` and print a new heading each time the event changes.

Like this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT users.u_name, events.e_id, events.e_title
FROM reservations
INNER JOIN events
ON reservations.r_event_id = events.e_id
INNER JOIN users
ON reservations.r_s_id = users.u_id
ORDER BY events.e_id";

$res = mysql_query($SQL);

$last_event = NULL;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    // check if curser moved to new event
    if (!$last_event || $last_event <> $row['e_id']) {

        // output heading for event
        echo $row['e_title'], '<br />', PHP_EOL;

        // remember ID of current event
        $last_event = $row['e_id'];
    }

    // output attendee
    echo '- ', $row['u_name'], '<br />', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `GROUP BY`, just order by event, and add `DISTINCT` to your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    users.u_name, 
    events.e_id, 
    events.e_title
FROM users
    INNER JOIN reservations
    ON reservations.r_s_id = users.u_id
    INNER JOIN events
    ON reservations.r_event_id = events.e_id
ORDER BY events.e_title, users.u_name
```